# List column auto update with specific format

Tags: sharepoint-online, column

I need to have a `Project ID` column in a project named list.

The format would be

```
PROJ0001
PROJ0010
PROJ0099
PROJ0100
```

and so on. These I'd will be auto populated while creating any new item in the list.

How can this be done in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

The ID value is a sequential numbering for List Items.

You can use the Calculated Column Formula:

```
=TEXT( [ID] , "PROJ0000" )
```

Only one caveat: Newly created items have a 0 value for the ID column, because the ID value is determined after all Formulas have been calculated.
*That is why you don't see* ID *listed as usable column when editting a Formula*

Trick is to create a (on new item) Workflow which writes the ID value to a second column MyID so you can use:

```
=TEXT( [MyID] , "PROJ0000" )
```

You can trigger the [ID update without a Workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160426/create-unique-number-with-listitem-id-and-today-age-in-calculated-column-for/160447#160447), but that is a more advanced usage.

Comment: Thanks Danny but the format of the values in project id would remain same means PROJ0010 not PROJ00010. Can you let me know how it can be maintained.

Comment: Anyone else helping me on this...